# How to change date modified of C:\$RECYCLE.BIN?

Tags: windows, powershell

Since you can only view the C:\$RECYCLE.BIN Folder when you uncheck (Hide protected Operating System Files) you can't change the date modified through the usual way with PowerShell:

```
$file = Get-Item C:\Path\TO\File.txt
$file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
```

or

```
$folder = Get-Item C:\folder1
$folder.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
```

When calling `Get-Item C:\$RECYCLE.BIN`, I get the following error:

> ```
> Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\.bin' because it does not exist.
> At line:1 char:9
> + $file = Get-Item C:\$Recycle.bin
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\.bin:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
> ```

How would I go about changing the date modified of it?

Comment: As to add on to @Thomas's answer, the `$RECYCLE` variable gets expanded when you try to do that so you must either escape the `$` with a backtick or use single quotes to prevent the variable from being expanded. A powershell rule of thumb is that paths generally should use quotes one way or another whether it is double (to avoid spaces causing errors) and single (to both avoid spaces causing errors and variables causing errors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` contains `$`, PowerShell tries to evaluate the variable `$RECYCLE`, which is empty. Thus, the resulting path `C:\.bin` cannot be found. Quote your path with single quotes (`'`) to prevent PowerShell from evaluating your string and also add the `-Force` parameter as it is a system directory:

```bsh
Get-Item -Path 'C:\$RECYCLE.BIN' -Force
```

---

You can then access your files and change the `LastWriteTime` as you already tried in your question:

```bsh
$fileObject = Get-Item -Path 'C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3323847664-626704455-790384891-1001\$RT8USDF.txt' -Force
$fileObject.LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

Comment: Well it seems like it didn't work nvm... If I change last modified date it says the changed date in the console but it doesn't actually change the folder's date modified or the Recycle Bin's date modified... hm

Comment: @CyberLost It works at least on my machine... Are you saying that it works in the console, but not in the GUI? Are you aware that the GUI displays only the `CreationTime` when right clicking a folder and displaying "properties"?